# Python equivalent of password encryption from RSA key Java code

Tags: java, python, rsa, m2crypto

Below is the Java code that uses rsa private key (ex: `MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvBXTe278Lwg2MoI7iGKolSYuF+sNFKrsZplxCN9x0kItU3KIf8+1q60ILLwLewCEf7foxzpWp32j9YYU9vNBghuJ7BHcDYTffTRcv+QdNno491j701Hq7DIw13AGCQQTRcnfclvblnytIEWoQsiUvPJcdiWgqJIX3IQGA47a+uwIDAQAB`)

and encrypts a plain string `test123` using rsa public key (public key generated from rsa private key above)

```
byte[] array = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key); KeyFactorykf = KeyFactory.getInstance(“RSA”);
publicKey = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(array)); Cipher = Cipher.getInstance(“RSA”);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal (“test123”.getBytes(“UTF-8”));
String output = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(result);
```

I tried m2crypto library to do so in python:

```
import base64
from M2Crypto import BIO, RSA

pubkey = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvBXTe278Lwg2MoI7iGKolSYuF+sNFKrsZplxCN9x0kItU3KIf8+1q60ILLwLewCEf7foxzpWp32j9YYU9vNBghuJ7BHcDYTffTRcv+QdNno491j701Hq7DIw13AGCQQTRcnfclvblnytIEWoQsiUvPJcdiWgqJIX3IQGA47a+uwIDAQAB'

# encryption
text = "test123".encode('utf-8')  # Plaintext
pub_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(pubkey.encode('utf-8'))  # Public key string
pub_rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(pub_bio)  # Load public key
secret = pub_rsa.public_encrypt(text, RSA.pkcs1_padding)  # Public key encryption
sign = base64.b64encode(secret)  # Ciphertext base64 encoding
print(sign)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encrypt_rsa_public_key.py", line 13, in <module>
    pub_rsa = RSA.load_pub_key_bio(pub_bio)  # Load public key
  File "/Users/umeshpathak/env/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 444, in load_pub_key_bio
    rsa_error()
  File "/Users/umeshpathak/env/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/RSA.py", line 333, in rsa_error
    raise RSAError(Err.get_error_message())
M2Crypto.RSA.RSAError: no start line
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: the library might expect to get the key in PEM format so enclosed between `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` also with new line at the end of each.

Comment: @michalk, thanks
I updated `pubkey` as:
```pubkey = f'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n{pubkey}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'```
And now it seems to work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library that you are using might expect to get the public key in PEM format i.e. enclosed between `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`. So you would have to change your `pubkey` to :

```
pubkey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' \
         'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvBXTe278Lwg2MoI7iGKolSYuF+sNFKrsZplxCN9x0kItU3KIf8+1q60ILLwLewCEf7foxzpWp32j9YYU9vNBghuJ7BHcDYTffTRcv+QdNno491j701Hq7DIw13AGCQQTRcnfclvblnytIEWoQsiUvPJcdiWgqJIX3IQGA47a+uwIDAQAB' \
         '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

the line breaks are important.